# useradd for no home and no loging

Tags: useradd

I want to make an user that have no home folder and no login ability.

```
sudo useradd -s /bin/false [demouser]
```

I omitted `-m` parameter since that makes the home folder for the `demouser`.

I did `-s /bin/false` option for making this `demouser` cannot login.

- Have I done it right?
- Is the the option `-s /bin/nologin` the same as above?

Comment: For your second question see [What's the difference between /sbin/nologin and /bin/false](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/whats-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false)

Comment: I followed the link steeldriver gave me. It was very helpful.